# Not able to create dynamic class in android

Tags: android

I want to call a class depending on the button clicked.

Precisely i want to have an object of type class whom i can assign a class name which is already present in the package. I am not getting how to create one.

for ex. i have ten classes named one to ten.
If i click first button i should go to class one by intent like

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,calledprog.class);
```

where calledprog can change its name from one to ten.

I hope you got my question and please pardon me for my wrong english.

Comment: Try declaring your intent object outside of the switch statement, and then initializing it within them.

Comment: sorry but i dint got you.

i dont know how to declare an dynamic class variable i tried using class classname;
from this classname i want to call any other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create array of all classes and when you click on i-th button - get i-th element from array:

```
private static final Class<?>[] NUMBERS = {One.class, Two.class, ...};

// Method that handles button clicks.
int num = // get number of button
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NUMBERS[num]);
```

Comment: getting error here
    `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NUMBERS[0].class);`

Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected MainActivity.java /BasicCProgram/src/com/ashsoft/basiccprogram line 26 Java Problem

Comment: @ashwinbhy don't add `class` after `NUMBERS[0]`.

Comment: Oh. 
Sorry was a silly mistake..
Thanks a ton for the support.